# spring batch job with partitions : setting clientInfo in an Oracle session not working for all partitions

Tags: oracle, encryption, parallel-processing, spring-batch, database-partitioning

I have a  spring batch job using partions and reader is JdbcCursorItemReader, so in this reader I need an authorisation to read correctely crypted data, so when I declare my reader a call the method just bellow .
the problem is that somme partions read null value for the field which need to be decrypted , the only reason is that the authorisation is not set ( I check in database and data are not null), so why it's work for some partions and not for all?

```
 private void authorize() {
        //Authorize
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.update(setClientInfo, authorization);
    }
```

and this is how i declare my reader

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['modulo']}") Integer modulo)
      throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(SQL_FILE);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()));
        String query = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
        query = query.replace(MODULO_LABEL, String.valueOf(modulo));
        query = query.replace(GRID_SIZE_LABEL, String.valueOf(gridSize));
        authorize();
        JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> cursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        cursorItemReader.setSql(query);
        final int partitionSize = maxNumberCards / gridSize;
        cursorItemReader.setMaxItemCount(partitionSize);
        cursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        cursorItemReader.setRowMapper(myRowMapper);
        return cursorItemReader;
    }
```

and my job configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RefreshScope
public class MyFunctionJobConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    JdbcCursorItemReader<MyEntity> reader;
    @Value("${max-number-card-to-process}")
    private Integer MAX_NUMBER_CARD;
    @Value("${chunck-size:10}")
    private int chunckSize;
    @Value("${grid-size:1}")
    private int gridSize;

    private final static String JOB_DISABLED = "job is disabled, check the configuration file !";
    @Value("${job.enabled}")
    private boolean batchIsEnabled;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FUNCTIONAL_LOGGER");

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @RefreshScope
    public MyEntityWriter writer() {
        return new MyEntityWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @RefreshScope
    public MyFunctionProcessor processor() throws IOException {
        return new MyFunctionProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyPrationner partitioner() {
        return new MyPrationner();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step masterStep() throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
            .partitioner("MyFunctionStep", partitioner())
            .step(MyFunctionStep())
            .gridSize(gridSize)
            .taskExecutor(MyFunctionTaskExecutor())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor myFunctionTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyFunctionTaskExecutor_");
        int corePoolSize = gridSize + 2;
        int maxPoolSize = corePoolSize * 2;
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        taskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myFunctionStep() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("MyFunctionStep")
            .<MyEntity, MyEntity>chunk(chunckSize)
            .reader(reader)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(MAX_NUMBER_CARD)
            .skip(InvalidCardNumberException.class)
            .skip(TokenManagementException.class)
            .processor(processor())
            .listener(new MyEntityProcessListener())
            .writer(writer())
            .listener(new MyEntityWriteListener())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myFunctionJob(@Qualifier("MyFunctionStep") Step myFunctionStep)
        throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (!batchIsEnabled) {
            LOGGER.error(JOB_DISABLED);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("MyFunctionJob")
            .listener(new MyFunctionJobListener())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(masterStep())
            .end()
            .build();
    }

}
```

I try to run a spring batch job with partions to read data from oracle database( in the sql there is a decryption function ) this need to set an authorisation for every session of connexion

the problem when th batch run some partion not decrypt data and return null an the only reason fo that , is that the authorisation is not set

Answer (score 0):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` does not use a `JdbcTemplate`. It directly creates connections to the database from the data source object passed to it. So you should not be expecting to call `authorize` which operates on a separate `JdbcTemplate` instance to impact the behaviour of the `JdbcCursorItemReader`. You said it works for some partitions, and that's really surprising.

If you want to take control on how the connection to the database is configured and override the default settings (for example by adding some authorization attributes), you need to extend `JdbcCursorItemReader` and override the `protected void openCursor(Connection con)` method, something like:

```
class MyCustomJdbcCursorItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader {
    @Override
    protected void openCursor(Connection con) {
        super.openCursor(con);
        // con.setClientInfo(); // set client info as needed here
    }
}
```